# What is the default batch size in simple salesforce?

Tags: python, soql, simple-salesforce

I built a script that takes contact information from a Google sheet and updates/inserts the contacts in SFDC. I am wondering what the default batch size might be when I am running a query to update or insert the contacts.

Comment: How big is your data? Sounds like you should use the Bulk API 2.0. The batch size limits are mentioned here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.htm

Comment: The data set is being updated daily but it will be anywhere from 250 to 1,500 contacts. I will take a look at the Bulk API, I have a ton of processes that automatically run once a new contact is entered that is why I want a restriction on the batch size.

Answer (score 1):

The default batch size is **10,000** and is the maximum you can send in a bulk request using simple_salesforce.

From simple salesforce's documentation:

> You can use this library to access Bulk API functions. The data element can be a list of records of any size and by default batch sizes are 10,000 records and run in parrallel concurrency mode.

Although you can send batches of 10,000  records, Salesforce will process it 200 or 100 every 5 minutes depending on your Salesforce API version.

From Salesforce's documentation:

> The chunk size depends on the API version. In API version 20.0 and earlier, the chunk size is 100 records. In API version 21.0 and later, the chunk size is 200 records. There’s a 5-minute limit for processing each chunk.